# VHDL finite state machine counter with start

Tags: vhdl, counter

i pretty new of vhdl and i'm trying to learn how to do a FSM with vhdl. 
At moment i need a code that after a fixed count value, it give me back a pulse, in order to start a second FSM block.  (I have a recurring signal every 100 kHz, i need to count it and release this signal after a fixed number of counts).
Actually it work as free run, every time that it see this signal, it start to count, but realy i want to add a "start" signal, so it must start to count this signal after it see this start signal.

at moment my working code is:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.numeric_std.ALL;

entity counter is
Port (
    signal_in : in STD_LOGIC := '0'; --segnale di start
    clk : in  STD_LOGIC; --clock di ingresso
    reset  : in  STD_LOGIC; --ff reset
    signal_out: out STD_LOGIC; --gate in uscita
    count_val: in std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
    start : in STD_LOGIC := '0'


   );
end counter;

architecture behavioral of counter is
type state_type is (idle, count_up);
signal state : state_type;

begin
process (reset, clk, signal_in, start)
variable index : integer :=0;
variable countlen: integer;
variable count_v: std_logic;
variable countlen2 : std_logic;

begin

 countlen := to_integer(unsigned(count_val))-1;



if reset = '1' then  
  count_v := '0';
  index := 0;
  state <= idle;

else
--if start = '1' and
    --if rising_edge(clk) then
    if rising_edge(signal_in) then
    case state is
      when idle =>
        count_v :='0';
        index := 0;
        if (signal_in = '1') then
          state <= count_up;
          else
          state <= idle;
        end if;


      when count_up =>
        if(index < countlen) then
        state <=count_up;
        index := index + 1;
       elsif
        index = countlen then
        count_v := '1';
        state <=idle; 
        end if;        



      when others => null;
    end case;



  end if;
   end if;  

  signal_out <= count_v;

  end process; 


  end Behavioral;
```

Any attempt to work with cose with "start = 1" will stop the count. 
Please some one have some suggestion?

Kind REgards

Fulvio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome om StackOverflow. Your specification is not 100% clear. What difference do you make between `signal_in` and `start`? According to your code and to your explanations, they both seem to act as a starter.

Moreover, there are several strange things with your code:

1. your process seems to be a synchronous one, with asynchronous reset. Its sensitivity list should contain only the clock and the reset. And its body should be:

   ```
   process(clk, reset)
       <variable declarations>
   begin
       <NOTHING HERE>
       if reset = '1' then
           <reset code>
       elsif rising_edge(clk) then
           <regular code>
       end if;
       <NOTHING HERE>
   end process;
   ```
2. you are using `signal_in` as a clock and as a logic signal. This is extremely strange. Moreover, your `if (signal_in = '1') then` is always true (in the synthesis semantics) and thus useless.
3. You are initializing variables at declaration (`index`). This is not supported by some synthesizers and hardware targets. Moreover, even when supported, it works only at power up. If:

   - you intend to synthesize your code,
   - you want it to be portable across synthesizers and hardware targets,
   - you want to re-initialize signal and variables not only at power up but also when a reset input is asserted,

   prefer a real explicit reset, instead, and guarantee that it is always asserted after power up (or at the beginning of a simulation) for proper first initialization.
4. you declare variable `index` with a full integer range, that is, 32 bits minimum, while 8 bits would suffice. This is a potential waste of hardware resources.

It is difficult to propose a solution without a clear and complete specification but assuming you want to count only after `start` has been asserted and only when `signal_in` is asserted, the following may be a starting point:

```
process (clk, reset)
    variable index: natural range 0 to 255;
begin
    if reset = '1' then
        state      <= idle;   
        signal_out <= '0';
        index      := 0;
    elsif rising_edge(clk) then
        case state is
            when idle =>
                signal_out <= '0';
                index      := 0;
                if start = '1' then
                    state <= count_up;
                end if;
            when others =>
                if signal_in = '1' then
                    if index = to_integer(unsigned(count_val)) - 1 then
                        state      <= idle;
                        signal_out <= '1';
                    else
                        index := index + 1;
                    end if;
                end if;
        end case;
    end if;
end process;
```

Note that this is really synchronous of your clock `clk`. I suspect that you made a very common mistake: as you wanted to increment your counter when `signal_in` is asserted you decided more or less to use `signal_in` as a clock. This is not a real synchronous and safe design. In a real safe synchronous design you do not use logic signals as clocks. You have well identified clocks and you use only these as clocks. In your case there is one single clock: `clk`. If you want to do something synchronously when a logic signal is asserted, wait for the rising edge of your clock and then test the logic signal and take appropriate actions.

Comment: Just as note: unrelated (also called asynchronous) input signals should be first synchronized before you can safely use them with a clock.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your support. 
Yes the point is that i need to "decimate" (or count) a signal.
This signal had a width of 50-100ns and it repeat itself with a frequency of 100 kHz.
so in my mind, this signal will go in to "signal in". My FPGA is an Actel proasic3 with a clock of 40 MHz.
In my setup this signal will be always on, but i don't want that my FSM will start to count as it see the first "signal in" but only when i send a "start" signal for the number of count that i indicate. (Realy they ask to me the possibility to decimate this signal up to 65000 count, so for sure i need to use a 16bit vector instead of 8bit).
The async reset is here "just in case" i need to reset the whole fsm in the middle of some data record.

Hope to be more clear now what this code should do.

For Old fart, yes indeed all my signal coming outside the fpga will be first synchronized with a simple 2 ff synchronizer with the FPGA clock